# Coercing a scalar or an array to become an array

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I want a variable to always be an array, whether its a scalar or already an array.

So I normally do:

```
[variable].flatten
```

which is compatible with ruby-1.8.5, 1.8.7, 1.9.x.

With this method when `variable` is a string (`variable = "asdf"`), it gives me `["asdf"]`. If it's already an array (`variable = ["asdf","bvcx"]`), it gives me: `["asdf","bvcx"]`.

Does anyone have a better way? "Better" meaning more readable, more performant, succinct or more effective in other ways.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way I do, and think is the standard way, is using `[*...]`:

```
variable1 = "string"
variable2 = ["element1", "element2"]

[*variable1] #=> ["string"]
[*variable2] #=> ["element1", "element2"]
```

Comment: I didn't know lucapette's way, and that seems to work, but the way I show above works at about twice the speed.

Comment: On which implementation? YARV?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes. YARV in Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: I've confirmed the performance for this one is better, but both this and the Array(foo) method are good.

Comment: Note that this method will _always_ return a new Array. `Kernal#Array` will return the same object if it is given an Array.

Comment: Note that this may not do what you want if there are nils involved: `[*nil] -> []`, but `[nil].flatten -> [nil]`

Answer (score 17):

```
Array(variable)
```

should do the trick. It uses the little known [Kernel#Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) method.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like `Array.eat`. Most other methods either call `#to_a` or `#to_ary` on the object. If you where using `[ obj ].flatten` that might give surprising results. `#flatten` will also mangle nested arrays unless called with a level parameter and will make an extra copy of the array.

Active support provides `Array.wrap`, but that also calls `#to_ary`, which might or might not be to your liking, depending on your needs.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/wrap'

class Array

# Coerce an object to be an array. Any object that is not an array will become
# a single element array with object at index 0.
#
# coercing nil returns an empty array.
#
def self.eat( object )

  object.nil?              and return []
  object.kind_of?( Array ) and return object

  [object]

end

end # class Array

a = { a: 3 }

p [a].flatten        # => [{:a=>3}]
p [*a]               # => [[:a, 3]] -> OOPS 
p Array      a       # => [[:a, 3]] -> OOPS
p Array.wrap a       # => [{:a=>3}]
p Array.eat  a       # => [{:a=>3}]
```